# Trying to extract names of worksheets in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract names of worksheets within all excel workbooks in the folder selected. The codes doesn't run reminding type mismatch on IF row.

I am not really familiar with FSO, object and shell function in vba so if I did anything wrong please point out, thanks.

```
Sub extractname()

    Dim Fso, Fld, sFld, Fl
    Dim Wb As Workbook, Sheeet As Worksheet, Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Arr
    Dim count As Long

    count = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fld = Fso.getfolder(CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select folder", 0, "").Self.Path & "")
    Set Sheeet = ActiveSheet
        For Each Fl In Fld.Files
            'On Error Resume Next
            If Fl.Name Like "*.xls" Or "*.xlsm" Or "*.xlsx" Then
                count = count + 1
                Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Fl)
                ReDim Arr(count, 4)
                Arr(count, 1) = Wb.Worksheets(1).Name.Text
                Arr(count, 2) = Wb.Worksheets(2).Name.Text
                Arr(count, 3) = Wb.Worksheets(3).Name.Text
                Arr(count, 4) = Wb.Worksheets(4).Name.Text
                Wb.Close
            End If
        Next
    Sheeet.[B65536].End(3).Resize(count, 4) = Arr

End Sub
```

I expect 4 columns of worksheet names shall be tabulated but the code does not run.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
If Fl.Name Like "*.xls" Or "*.xlsm" Or "*.xlsx" Then
```

to

```
If Fl.Name Like "*.xls" Or Fl.Name Like "*.xlsm" Or Fl.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
```

Why not just use:

```
If Fl.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
```

---

**Edit 1**: modified code

the code below will get you what you want (if I understand your code intentions correctly).

```
Option Explicit

Sub extractname()

    Dim Fso, Fld, sFld, Fl
    Dim Wb As Workbook, Sheeet As Worksheet, Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Arr
    Dim count As Long, i As Long, ShtCount As Long

    count = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fld = Fso.getfolder(CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select folder", 0, "").Self.Path & "")
    Set Sheeet = ActiveSheet

    For Each Fl In Fld.Files
        ReDim Arr(1 To Fld.Files.count, 1 To 4)

        If Fl.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
            count = count + 1
            Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Fl)

            ' need to make sure each workbook has 4 sheet (not less)
            ShtCount = Wb.Worksheets.count
            If ShtCount > 4 Then ShtCount = 4

            For i = 1 To ShtCount
                Arr(count, i) = Wb.Worksheets(i).Name
            Next i

            Wb.Close
        End If
    Next Fl

    Sheeet.Range("B" & Sheeet.Cells(Sheeet.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Resize(count, 4) = Arr

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Cause I thought the excel file names are ended either with .xls or .xlsm or .xlsx?

Comment: @AnctorHu not sure I understand your question. Did the solution I offered worked ?

Comment: Now it reminds "Run-time error'424', object required"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub F()

    '// Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, xFile As File
    Dim strFolder$
    Dim book As Workbook

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select folder"
        If .Show() Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
    End With
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    For Each xFile In fso.GetFolder(strFolder).Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(xFile.Name) Like "xls*" Then
            Set book = Workbooks.Open(xFile.Path)
            '// Do your thing
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.
1) You can't redim the rows in VBA arrays

2) it errors if your file doesn't have exactly 4 worksheets
3) If you don't preserve the array when you redim it loses all data.

You could still use the FSO instead of the open folder dialog box macro.

```
Option Base 1  'so that the VBA array starts on row 1 and column 1, not 0,0
Sub Worksheet_names_in_Dir()
Dim direct As String
Dim Arr()
'
' directory Macro
Let direct = UseFolderDialogOpen & "\"
'
  Set Sht = ActiveSheet
f = Dir(direct & "\*.xls*", 7) 'sets f equal to the first file name and only files that are xls* files (XLSX, XLSB, XLSM)
Do While f <> ""        'loops until there are no more files in the direstory

    F1 = direct & f
                        Count = Count + 1
                        ReDim Preserve Arr(4, Count)  'you can't redim the rows in VBA, just the columns
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(F1)
                wkshts = wb.Sheets.Count    'count number of worksheets in file
                If wkshts > 4 Then wkshts = 4  'to only do 4 worksheets per file or less if there are less than 4 worksheets
                For i = 1 To wkshts
                    Arr(i, Count) = wb.Worksheets(i).Name
                Next i
                wb.Close


     f = Dir            'set f equal to the next file name in the directory

Loop

'this transposes the array and writes it to the active worksheet starting in A!, you can change this to fit your needs
Sht.Range("A1:D" & Count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr)

End Sub

Public Function UseFolderDialogOpen() As String
    Dim lngCount As Long

    ' Open the folder dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False 'only allows the user to pick one directory
        .Title = "pick directory"
        .Show

        ' Set Current Folder Path
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            UseFolderDialogOpen = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
        Next lngCount

    End With

End Function
```